# sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize: Doesn't count "\n" in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview, sizewithfont

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *substring = textView.text;
    substring = (text.length == 0 && range.length == 1) ?
    [substring substringToIndex: substring.length-1] : [substring stringByAppendingString: text];

    CGSize size = [substring sizeWithFont:textView.font
                        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, 200.0)];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, firstHeight);

    if(height != lastHeight)
    {
        CGFloat y = height - lastHeight;
        CHANGE_HEIGHT(textView, height);
        lastHeight = height;
    }   
    return YES;
}
```

The issue is that **`sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:`** gives me the **wrong height**.
For example if text is **"`Hello \n`"** `sizeWithFont` will not count the **"`\n`"**,
so **"Hello"** and **"`Hello \n`"** texts are in the **same height**.

Any needful help will be appreciated!

Comment: What if to add a space after \n? "Hello \n "

Comment: Tnx! It's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated but the way you get your `substring` is ignoring the range where the text is modified.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *textToMeasure = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    if ([textToMeasure hasSuffix:@"\n"]) {
        textToMeasure = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-", textView.text];
    ...
}
```